# Send GZIP compress the request to web service via WCF

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf, soap

There is similar question is available here
[GZIP compress the request to a remote web service via WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748527/gzip-compress-the-request-to-a-remote-web-service-via-wcf)
When I have implemented solution provided by expert
i.e. WCF client endpoint compression

here is my web.config file code

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="NAME" >
      <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip"/>
      <httpsTransport/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="MYENDPOINTURL"
      binding="customBinding"    bindingConfiguration="NAME"
      contract="ICONTRACT"  name="BulkRequestTransmitterPort" />
</client>
```

below is error I am getting

> Error: The content type text/xml;charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+msbin1+gzip). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 807 bytes of the response were: '
>       
>           
>               soapenv:Client
>               The request message must be sent using HTTP compression (RFC 1952 - GZIP).
>               
>                  TPE1112
>                   
>               
>           
>       
>   '

Can someone please tell me where I am doing wrong?``

Thanks